# connecting an existing database entity for authentication using NHibernate Identity and MVC AspNet.Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate, asp.net-identity

I successfully incorporated NHibernate to connect to my MySQL database. I am using the premade authentication in the MVC starter application. Now I’m using this:

https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.AspNet.Identity

to remove entity framework from the application and supplement NHibernate.AspNet.Identity instead. I manage to get the errors down to about 4 and I’m left with an error about ApplicationDbContext in IdentityConfig.cs.

This is because in the instructions it said to "Remove the ApplicationDbContext class completely." But it doesn’t say what to do with it. Because so much of the code is using ApplicationDbContext so a lot of things break.

My main problem or main question is. How to simply check the of the username and password that was input into a form exists in my database and if so, then set IsAuthenticated to true?

Comment: So you are moving an existing project from EF to nHibernate? If you took your ApplicationDbContext out, and there were references you will probably want to start by moving those to ISession references. This link is nHibernate to EF, but it shows similar issues  https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/04/22/migrating-from-nhibernate-to-entity-framework/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to override/intercept entity and making custom classes to check inputs against the mapped data.